# Should I use private classes in private projects?

Tags: c++, private, public

I'm facing writing a reasonably large program for a research project that will probably be used only by me, or possibly also by a small number of people that might take it over in the future. The point is - it's not a commercial application, and won't be publicly available. And my question - in such a case are there really any good arguments behind defining all my classes private rather than public?
The whole code is meant to be a job sequence scheduler. So, for example, I have a basic job class that looks like:

```
class Job {

private:    // should it be?
    int Jobid;

    int stack_row ; // horizontal positon in a stack
    int row_height ;    // position in a column of containers

    float ArrivalTime;
    float FinishTime;
    float GantryTime;

    float WaitingTime; // Job Start - Job Arrival
    float ReachableTime; // later time of Vehicle or YC arrival to job location

    float DueDate;
    float Tardiness; // max{0, Ci-di} Ci, Completion time = Finish time; di, DueDate
    float SlackTime;
    int type; // 1, Loading; 2, Unloading

} ;
```

Then there's a class for a sequence of jobs, simulation data, machines involved, and a number of other things. The point is, I end up with lot of classes, and even more components for them. All of them will be used either only by me, or a small number of other people. I could define all classes private, with `set_whatever()`, `get_whatever()` functions for all private components that need to be set or read, but is there really a point to it? A - it takes time. B - it doesn't make for a very legible code when I write

```
job_schedule.job_list[i].set_finish_time( job_schedule.job_list[i].get_ArrivaTime() +   job_schedule.job_list[i].get_ProcessingTime() ) ;
```

instead of

```
job_schedule.job_list[i] = job_schedule.job_list[i].Finish_Time + job_schedule.job_list[i].Processing_Time ;
```

So my question is - is there a really good reason I would stick to private classes in this case?
Or maybe there is a more elegant way to do

```
job_schedule.job_list[i].set_finish_time( job_schedule.job_list[i].get_ArrivaTime() + job_schedule.job_list[i].get_ProcessingTime() ) ;
```

while remaining private?

Comment: Ok, so I gather it's a sound idea to stick to defining all setters and getters, because in the long run they're more flexible and less likely to cause you bugs. Should anyone have anything more to add, please go ahead.

Comment: Getters and Setters improve maintenance (somewhat) but are really only suited for *Bundle of Data* (ie classes that act as mere containers of several related properties with no interaction between them). As soon as you have correlation between properties, they become a blight.

Comment: That's the thing - I have related properties that do correlate - i.e. finish time of a job being a function of start time and processing time. Which is why I would rather find a better solution than a long line which is just a set() function with two get() functions in the arguments to calculate finish = start + processing.

Comment: In this case, you have two solutions. You can either keep your one class, and provide getters for all properties but only setters that combine properties (ie `set(Time start, Duration process)`). Another solution is to split the class into several meaningful classes: `class JobSchedule { public: Time getStart() const; Duration getProcessing() const; void set(Time start, Duration processing); /**/ };` and then compose your `Job` class with those meaningful blocks. The blocks are true classes (with invariant and strong correlation between properties), and the `Job` is a mere collection.

Answer (score 7):

There is more to `private` than dependency management.

Information hiding is good as it lessens maintenance, but what's the point of having a class if you just treat it as a tuple of data ?

You should think about the interface of your class, and instead of providing a bunch of getters/setters so that anybody can just manipulate anything, you should strive to define meaningful methods.

Remember than source code should be readable first and foremost.

Comment: Indeed I'm using here classes just to group related data. And I think defining set and get for all those components is ugly. But apart for just treating all those classes as public don't have a good idea on how to go about the problem otherwise (but I am also trying to get a good answer as to why or why not keep them private/public in my case).
And why is it a crime to make a class to tie together components that are logically related (i.e. characteristics of a job)?

Comment: Yep, getter/setters are such a waste of time in 99% of the cases.

Comment: @Puchatek: it is not a crime, in this case you effectively have a Bundle of Data (tuple-like), and you can use a `struct` or setters/getters depending on your habit. It is just that in typical OO, this is not generally considered a `class`, even though the language more or less force you to cram it into one.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is meant to be maintained for some time and it's not a one time project I strongly recommend using information hiding, i.e. private member variables and public accessors (setters and getters). Because you may never know when you will want to add a functionality when some propery changes. At that time you will need a setter function that does more than setting the member variable but you'll have to refactor all previously written code.

So I'd say go with the better design. It's a little harder to type but a typical piece of code is typed only once and read many more times.

Comment: "It's a little harder to type but a typical piece of code is typed only once and read many more times." I don't get it. How do getters and setters improve readability?

Comment: If just using your class as just a tuple of data as Matthieu suggests, and you're sure and certain that this will never change, then you're right. In that case I prefer to declare it as a struct instead of a class, as a reminder for anyone who may be reading the source code, including myself.

Comment: @cyco130 - They do depend on each other a bit, as I just described in the comment under the question. Would you say that changes anything?

Comment: If it's just "related data" and nothing else I'd say go with public members. But you will have to *do something* with that data, wouldn't you? At that point you'll need **methods** and it's gonna be a fully fledged class. An at any point if you need to change something when the data changes you *will* be regretting not implementing at least the setters. But as I said, if you're 100% sure that you only need some bundled data, you can of course use a struct or a class with public members. There's nothing wrong with it per se.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is no such thing as private or public classes. You have private, protected or public members or classes.

As to writing a lot of classes, using inheritance and encapsulation (information hiding) - I would strongly suggest that you do. This will ensure that the code that you develop is more likely to be free from errors and in the long run easier to understand, maintain and modify.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for the classes but keep the data private.

Why not `job_schedule.set_finish_time(i, now());` or similar?